# wp_insert_posts Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Tags: loop, wp-insert-post, save-post

I'm having a weird problem I have written the code as below:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_post_func');

function save_post_func(){
    include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');

    $rss = fetch_feed($url);

    if (!is_wp_error($rss)) {
        //ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 1000); <-- Doesn't work

        $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5);

        $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);

        foreach ($rss_items as $item) { // count($rss_items) = 5 ???
            wp_insert_post(array('post_title' => 'a')); // inserts > 100 records ???
        }

    }

}
```

Displays this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Any help? Where is the problem all seems ok...

Comment: Currently you insert post, if you save a post and this run in a endless loop. I think you must change the hook to `init`, not `save_post`.

Comment: No no it is in the save post hook.The error only occurs when i save the post and i try to insert another post

Comment: @AntonioPapa I see you fixed it, nice one! @bueltge is right - if you use `wp_insert_post` on your `save_post` hook, you trigger an infinite loop! Hence why removing the hook on first-run solves the issue :)

Comment: Yep you are right i thought i made a error in the loop :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem I've added this line before the insertion of the posts.

```
remove_action('save_post', __FUNCTION__);
```

final code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_post_func');

function save_post_func(){
    remove_action('save_post', __FUNCTION__);

    include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');

    $rss = fetch_feed($url);

    if (!is_wp_error($rss)) {

        $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5);

        $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);

        foreach ($rss_items as $item) { 
            wp_insert_post(array('post_title' => 'a')); 
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the code you were using was creating an infinite loop. You should unhook the function before calling `wp_insert_post` and add it back again when done. Here is the sample code you should use:

```
function save_post_func( $post_id ){
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action('save_post', 'save_post_func');

        include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');

        $rss = fetch_feed($url);

        if (!is_wp_error($rss)) {

            $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5);

            $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);

            foreach ($rss_items as $item) { 
                wp_insert_post(array('post_title' => 'a')); 
            }

        }

        // re-hook this function
        add_action('save_post', 'save_post_func');
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_post_func');
```

More info from [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops)