# "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached" after adding a new filter

Tags: php, filters, title, fatal-error

I am trying to filter my post title for a specific page and when a form is submitted on that page , for this I am trying to filter my title . Here is the code

```
function filter_title_after() {

   $current_page_id = get_the_ID();
   if($current_page_id == 58 && !empty($_POST)){
       $title = "Congratulation";
   } else {
       $title = the_title();
   }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'filter_title_after');
```

After adding this filter , I am getting an error ""Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

I have already looked several stackexchange question , but none of the came to any help

[wp_insert_posts Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147505/wp-insert-posts-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-ab)
[Problem:Save Several Duplicate posts in The Database and then Error nesting level of '100' reached](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177884/problemsave-several-duplicate-posts-in-the-database-and-then-error-nesting-leve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_title()` calls your function again. If you want to avoid that, remove the callback inside of your function:

```
function filter_title_after() {
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    // the rest of your code.
```

But you shouldn’t call `the_title()` in your function at all: it **prints** the title – this is not what you want – and you get the original title and ID already as an argument from WordPress. Use it.

Also, testing for POST requests should be done by checking `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ]`.

```
function filter_title_after( $title, $post_id ) {

    if ( ! is_singular() )
        return $title;

    if ( 58 !== (int) $post_id )
        return $title;

    if ( 'POST' !== $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] )
        return $title;

    return "Congratulation";
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'filter_title_after', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks @toscho , that solves my problem and learned something new . Have a great day .