# How to change post status from publish to draft using hook in wordpress?

Tags: posts, plugin-development, functions, hooks, post-status

I want to change the status of already publish post to draft using its id.

```
   add_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_status', 1 );
function change_post_status( $post_id ){
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => 1,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
    );
    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'change_post_status');
    if( $post_id == 1 ){
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
    }
    // re-hook this function
    add_action('save_post', 'change_post_status');
}
```

I want to change the status of specific post which has id = 1 to be changed to draft.It is working but leading to

> Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

why it is getting this error ?

What I think is it is running when post is updated or saving , I want to just run the function independent of save or update action like on `wp_init` or `wp_admin` or `admin_init` some other hook, is it possible.

Comment: I am not sure its right way to do but it seems your code is working for me and changed status of post to draft and if you want to do it for post having ID 1 then you can apply condition  `if($post_id == 1)`

Comment: @jas where before `wp_update_post()` ??

Comment: @jas Can you post it as answer ?

Comment: just added in your function at start and enclosed all code in that condition.

Comment: @jas that not worked for me.

Comment: I have changed answer and its working for me, please check

Answer (score 2):

In your `functions.php` :

```
add_action('publish_post', 'check_user_publish', 10, 2);

function check_user_publish ($post_id, $post) {

    if($post_id == 1){
    $query = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
    );
    wp_update_post( $query, true );

    }

}
```

Comment: It not worked for me, how ever can you give me some idea how I should debug , so that I can show some error or something .

Comment: Adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your config file can show error if any is there.

Comment: sorry using these also not resulting in any error.

Comment: Please try updated answer I am also trying by search and reading but I think to remove hook we can use `remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );` like you did to avoid infinte loop

Comment: where I should use it ?

Comment: I have also spend more than 20hrs from tomorrow, but no luck and getting no ideas :( thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: As far I can tell its working for me and I am doing it in Twenty Fifteen , its working for you or not ?

Comment: I am also using same theme 2015. It seems like a magical power working against me, sorry but I am really feeling weak on this .

Comment: I am using wordpress 4.3.1

Comment: I am also using same version and have tested again, I assure you that its working for me. But sorry I am not able to check what else is interrupting.

Comment: I am also getting no idea why not working for me :(

Comment: Can you check, I have updated my status with new code.

Comment: try using this inside your function `remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );`

Comment: again not getting it working, no idea what I am doing :(

Comment: please have a look if this helps: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178747/maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-after-adding-a-new-filter

Comment: I have seen that one, let me try another time.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a hook, it has to have the same priority as when you add the hook. You add_action with a priority of 1. If you want to remove the action, you need to remove it with a priority of 1. See [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action).

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_status', 1 );
function change_post_status( $post_id ){
  $my_post = array(
    'ID' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'draft',
  );
  // unhook this function, making sure to use the same priority, so it doesn't loop infinitely
  remove_action('save_post', 'change_post_status', 1 );
  if( $post_id == 1 ){
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
  }
  // re-hook this function with the initial priority
  add_action('save_post', 'change_post_status', 1 );
}
```